# What is the maximum value allowed to push onto the stack?

Tags: c, assembly, att

In C assembly, the following code gives me the error when compiling,

> output.s:5: Error: operand type mismatch for 'push'
>
> output.s:6: Error: operand type mismatch for 'push'

```
.globl compute

compute:
pushq $9223372036854775807
pushq $9223372036854775807
popq  %r10
popq  %r11
imulq %r10, %r11
pushq %r11
popq  %rax
retq
```

And I think it's because the constants that are pushed are too large.

Comment: Well, use a calculator to find out what the largest quadword is in decimal

Comment: @MartinJames and that's 9223372036854775807, if signed. Different problem.